# how to extract the string from two delimiter strings using sed or awk or bash?

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I'm not that frequent with awk or sed. Appreciate your assistance for below:

I have a bash shell variable $VAR with value :

```
DEFINE QLOCAL ('IIB.TESTQUEUE.MODULE') +
DESCR('Input queue for A to B') +
LIKE('MY.LOCALQ.TEMP') +
REPLACE
```

I want to extract the value `IIB.TESTQUEUE.MODULE` 
between `QLOCAL<0 or more spaces>('`and   `')` from the shell variable $VAR.

I framed the below regex based on other existing questions and an online regex tool but this is not printing anything when i try embed this regex in awk or sed.

[image: awk/sed/grep to extract the desired string]

Comment: I'm trying to exclude single quotes  with slight modification.```$ echo $MQSCCMD | sed 's/.*QLOCAL*('\([^)]*\).*/\1/'```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'  ... sees escaping the single quote isn't working.

Comment: You can't escape **anything** inside bash single-quotes. The second single-quote it sees terminates the string. Single-quotes can't appear inside a single-quoted string.

Comment: `grep -oP "your_pattern" file`? I see you have `*` quantified patterns in your lookbehind though. Can I suggest a PCRE regex to use with GNU `grep` / `pcregrep`?

Comment: Using basic regex `sed "s/^.*QLOCAL[ ][(][']\([^']*\)['][)].*$/\1/" <<<$var`

Comment: You're getting all sorts of weird/wonderful/impossible results from trying to execute the simplest command which means there's something you're not telling us about how you're executing the command. You're saying things that are wrong, e.g. in [your first comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55910843/how-to-extract-the-string-from-two-delimiter-strings-using-sed-or-awk-or-bash/55911187?noredirect=1#comment98477115_55910843), that code isn't escaping any single quote, and not telling us error messages so we'd have to see a actual complete screen shot to help you.

Comment: Hi @EdMorton : sorry to confuse u. i meant i was tweaking given solution to exclude single quotes also from result with above given solution. now its working. thank u for help.

Answer (score 2):

The first part in your regex is a variable width positive lookbehind:

```
(?<=
  TOPIC \s*\('|
  QLOCAL\s*\('|
  QALIAS\s*\('|
  SUB   \s*\('
)
```

It is advised to merge literal words into its own alternation group and use a `\K` operator that would discard the text matched so far from the current memory buffer: `(?:TOPIC|QLOCAL|QALIAS|SUB)\s*\('\K`.

The rest can be used as is with `-oP` options and a GNU `grep`:

```
grep -oP "(?:TOPIC|QLOCAL|QALIAS|SUB)\s*\('\K.*?(?='\))" file
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K0G3tI/1) and an [online `grep` demo](https://ideone.com/ptE7c6):

```
s="DEFINE QLOCAL ('IIB.TESTQUEUE.MODULE') +
DESCR('Input queue for A to B') +
LIKE('MY.LOCALQ.TEMP') +
REPLACE"
grep -oP "(?:TOPIC|QLOCAL|QALIAS|SUB)\s*\('\K.*?(?='\))" <<< "$s"
# => IIB.TESTQUEUE.MODULE
```

Comment: res=$(echo $s | grep -oP "(?:TOPIC|QLOCAL|QALIAS|SUB)\s*\('\K.*?(?='\))") , I'm trying to capture the result of this command but this isn't working. Please help.

Comment: @learner `echo $s` is not the same as `echo "$s"`. Always quote your variables unless you have a specific NEED not to. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes.

Comment: @EdMorton  noted with thanks. ill keep in mind.as u said i tried with "$s". still i do not see any value inside variable s.  when i echo s, i see my input thats bejng piped to the grep and when i run entire command, i see the result but its not being stored in Variable res.

Comment: @learner No idea why it does not [work](https://ideone.com/syiYy0) for you.

Answer (score 2):

Remember the string that matches:

```
echo "${VAR}" | sed -n "s/.*QLOCAL *('\([^']*\)').*/\1/p"
```

Offtopic: use lowercase for shell variables.

EDIT: Removed `[]` around space as @EdMorton said.

Comment: @learner the above will work robustly with any sed in any shell on  any UNIX box so you might want to focus on testing with this solution to remove any possible sources of failure beyond pilot error.

Comment: yes. this is working without any issues. im trying to capture the result using $() into a shell variable but i do not see value in result variable. not sure y this isn't working.

Comment: Did you try `newvar=$(echo "${VAR}" | sed -n "s/.*QLOCAL *('\([^']*\)').*/\1/p")` without spaces around the `=` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo "$var" | grep -oP "QLOCAL *\('\K[^']+"

IIB.TESTQUEUE.MODULE
```

not sure, why you have a problem in assignment

```
$ val=$(echo "$var" | grep -oP "QLOCAL *\('\K[^']+")
$ echo "$val"
IIB.TESTQUEUE.MODULE
```

Comment: i'm trying to capture result of this command as below. res=$(echo "${mqsc_cmd}" | sed -n "s/.*QLOCAL *('\([^']*\)').*/\1/p") , but $res has empty.  is it possible to capture this way ?

Comment: @learner of course but you're asking about a sed solution under a grep answer. If you have a question about a script someone posted in an answer then ask about it in a comment under **that** answer, not under some other answer.

Comment: my bad. i tested both above and this answer. i mis pasted my test here.

Comment: when i run the above command, im getting the response but when i place the above command inside S=$() , its not storing the result in S. i tried placing in single quotes but its throwing error.

Comment: Putting it in single quotes won't produce the output you want but it won't throw an errror.

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple cut command :
`echo $VAR|cut -d' -f2`

Comment: yeah i tested it. its not giving any result.

Comment: @learner if it's not giving **any** result then the problem is on your end (e.g. either you provided sample input that doesn't look like you're real input or you copy/pasted this code wrong).. Given the sample input you provided this code will produce some output, just not what you asked for.

Comment: Actually I stand corrected, it would produce the output you wanted since it's leaving $VAR unquoted which is inadvisable due to it's potential side-effects but in this case unless you got unlucky with globbing, input values, etc. it would probably produce the output you asked for (but still don't do it as it's the wrong approach).